# RobotFramework: Switching window after clicking into a new window

Tags: robotframework

Is there a way to adjust the focus (i.e bring to front) the second window after a click a link that goes to this second window in RobotFramework? I have some code that does screenshot after click and it only shows the first window

```
Click link  xpath=//*[contains(., "Download certificate")]
sleep  20
Select Window    Title=Certificate
Page Screenshot  Completion-Certificate
```

I know that the title of the popup window is Certificate but i get error

```
ValueError: Unable to locate window with title 'Certificate'
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do it by adding the following script-

```
Switch Window  locator=NEW
//This will take you to the latest window launched.
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are trying to test pop window which appears when you click on a link. You can use below solution,

```
Select Window    ${windowId}    # Focus popup/required window
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case following will do the required:

```
Select Window    locator=Certificate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Handle Lookup Window
Select Window    NEW      #comment: It will automatically move to new window
${tempB}=    Get Title
Log To Console    New window is : \ ${tempB}    # to verify the name in console
Select Frame    //*[@title='Search']            # optional sometimes elements are within frames ,so first need to access frame
Input Text    id=lksrch    hello
Click Element    //*[@value=' Go! ']
Unselect Frame                                  # going back to page
Select Frame    //*[@title='Results']           #selecting another frame
Click Element    id=jobdone 
Select Window                                    #once the jobdone button is clicked my pop up browser window is automatically get closed.so going back to parent browser.
```

note: line started using # are comments for understanding purpose only
Thanks!

Comment: "Handle Lookup Window" is the test case/keyword name which you have to create. Except 1st line please give 4 space to all as indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to multiple windows by title, URL or Window Handle ID. For this purpose use "Select Window" keyword from Robot Framework.

Example 1:

```
open browser  http://qaTechTesting.com Chrome
click element  (//img[@alt='Raghwen Linkedin Profile'])[1]
Select Window  Raghwendra Sonu
```

Example 2:

```
open browser  http://qaTechTesting.com Chrome
click element (//img[@alt='Raghwen Linkedin Profile'])[1]
@{list1}  get window handles
:FOR  ${Win} in ${list1}
\  Select Window   ${Win}
```

For more details read this: http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Window

Answer (score -1):

```
${windows}=    Get Window Handles
log    les fenêtres
log    ${windows}
Switch Window    ${windows}[1]
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?